# Is possible to include an assembly code to php script?

Tags: php, assembly

I mean something like this:

```
asm(

 //assembly code here
 mov dx, 4 // etc...


)
```

asm() - php function

is possible?

Answer (score 8):

No, it isn't possible. The closest you can come is to use `exec()` or similar functions to call external programs or scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

PHP scripts are compiled to bytecode which is specific to its particular virtual machine (assuming Zend Engine here). As such, you are not able to mix native and PHP code with the standard distribution.

It is however possible to write C extensions for PHP, in which you can use inline assembly.